# Does java perform GC recursively?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Probably this is a silly question.
When a object is marked for garbage collection, does java also marks the contained objects for garbage collection?

I mean,

```
class ContainerClass {
    ContainedClass obj1, obj2;  
    //Constructor
    ContainerClass() {
    obj1 = new ContainedClass ();
    obj2 = new ContainedClass ();
    }
  // main
    public static void main( String args[]) {
        ContainerClass  c = new ContainerClass();
        c = null ; // c is mared for GC. The question is c.obj1 and c.obj2 is also marked?
    }   
}
```

Comment: Longer answer [here](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/how-does-garbage-collection-work/)... :-)

Comment: Check also the included link: http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/whitepapers/memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if **only** the `ContainerClass` object has references to them, then the `ContainedClass` objects will become eligible for garbage collection at the same moment that the `ContainerClass` object itself become eligible.

Note that the actual *collection* of these objects can happen independently.

Comment: Ya. I assume "ONLY" container class has object references to it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is in some ways back to front.  Objects are not marked for collection, instead they are marked for keeping.

The garbage collector marks objects which are still in use, starting with active stack frames and all static variables and so on, following references it finds.  Each object the garbage collector finds is marked as being in use and will not be collected.

So child objects are not marked for collection, instead they are just not marked for keeping because their parent object isn't either.

(This is certainly true of a Mark and Sweep Garbage Collector which is the default for most JVMs.  Other Garbage Collectors may behave differently.)

Answer (score 1):

An object is ready to be garbage collected if there is no live thread that holds a reference to the object anymore, directly or indirectly. So yes, the contained objects are also ready to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

For you special example: yes, the contained objects will be marked for gc, but not, because the container is collected. They are marked because *after* the container is gone, no other objects holds a reference to the `ContainedClass` instances.

So in general, no, it is not recursive. Each and every instance is tested individually if it can be collected. The *contained instances* are not part of the container class, they live their own life. The container just holds some sort of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> Does java perform GC recursively ?

No.  A decent garbage collector does not use simple recursion for marking.  If it did, then marking long linked lists would require the marking algorithm to use a very deep stack to mark it.  That would be a significant problem.

There are a number of strategies that GC implementors can use to avoid excessive recursion:

- You don't actually use recursion.  You use a mark stack and an iterative algorithm ... which is more space efficient.
- Tricks can be used to minimize stack depth when traversing deep lists ... if you know where the depth is; e.g. which is the `next` field.
- The Knuth and Boehm-Demers-Weiser have ways of dealing with an overflowing mark stack that involve spilling the stack and then picking up the pieces.
- The Deutsch-Schorr-Waite algorithm uses pointer reversal and hence no mark stack at all.
- and so on.

If you want more details, refer to ["Garbage Collection: Algorithms for Automatic Dynamic Memory Management"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471941484) by Richard Jones and Rafael Lins, 1996.  (There's a new GC book called ["The Garbage Collection Handbook: The Art of Automatic Memory Management"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420082795) by Richard Jones, Antony Hosking and Eliot Moss due out later this year!!)

(Nit pick: the GC doesn't mark objects for garbage collection.  It marks them for as non-garbage ... and throws away the objects that are NOT marked.)